# Is there a way to retrieve distinct results (based on ID) by restructuring this SQL query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, count, distinct

This query is retrieving several counts, and the first one is a distinct count based upon "maintid". Is there a way to make the other counts distinct based upon maintID as well, while they are also looking for thetype/enteredby?

```
SELECT 
    datepart(mm, m.creationdate) AS themonth, 
    datepart(yyyy, m.creationdate) AS theyear, 
    count(DISTINCT m.maintid) AS total, 
    count(nullif(m.thetype, '1')) AS regular, 
    count(nullif(m.thetype, '2')) AS multi, 
    count(nullif(m.thetype, 11)) AS quick, 
    count(nullif(m.enteredby, 'WriteMonthly')) AS wm, 
    Count(case when m.thetype=10 then 1 else null end) as Errors,         
    Count(case when m.thetype=12 then 1 else null end) as FOH 
FROM 
    Maintlist AS m 
RIGHT JOIN 
    TypeList AS t ON t.typekey = m.thetype 
LEFT JOIN 
    MaintNotes AS mn ON m.maintid = mn.maintid 
WHERE 
    mn.enteredby in ('210', '181', '229', '240', '266', '284', '291', '238', '239', '272', '273') 
GROUP BY 
    datepart(mm, m.creationdate), datepart(yyyy, m.creationdate) 
ORDER BY 
    datepart(yyyy, m.creationdate) DESC, datepart(mm, m.creationdate) DESC
```

Comment: Tag the dbms used. (Some non-ANSI SQL there.)

Comment: Which DBMS (vendor and version)?

Comment: LEFT JOIN (executing as inner join) combined with RIGHT JOIN... Just too confusing for most people. Stick to LEFT JOINs if needed. It's easier to understand "main table left join optional data" instead of "optional data right join main table".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to count distinct `MaintId`.  If so:

```
SELECT datepart(month, m.creationdate) AS themonth,
       datepart(year, m.creationdate) AS theyear, 
       count(DISTINCT m.maintid) AS total, 
       count(distinct case when m.thetype <> 1 then m.maintid end) as regular,
       count(distinct case when m.thetype <> 2 then m.maintid end) as multi,
       count(distinct case when m.thetype <> 11 then m.maintid end) as quick,
       count(distinct case when m.enteredby <> 'WriteMonthly' then m.maintid end) AS wm, 
       . . .
```

This is a direct translation of your logic.  However, I'm pretty sure that you intend:

```
       count(distinct case when m.thetype = 1 then m.maintid end) as regular,
```

rather than:

```
       count(distinct case when m.thetype <> 1 then m.maintid end) as regular,
```